# Slack OAuth : Invalid permissions requested for local testing

Tags: slack, slack-api

For my local testing 
I am trying to get and save the user's access token from slack.

The first step is to get user's permission, I am trying to redirect the user to the following URL -

```
 https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope=commands,bot&client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/slack-verify/
```

The request then redirects the user(currently me) to

```
https://<MY-WORKSPACE>.slack.com/oauth?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fslack-verify%2F&state=&scope=commands%2Cbot&user_scope=&granular_bot_scope=1&team=&install_redirect=&single_channel=0&tracked=1
```

Ideally it should return with a code in GET parameters, but it displays an error on the screen -

```
<APP NAME> could not be installed. Error details
Invalid permissions requested
```

What is wrong here?

Edit : Replaced localhost with an ngrok URL as well, but that does not work as well.

steps to reproduce

```
 https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope=commands,bot&client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000/slack-verify/
```

just put your client id and redirect uri local if any.

Comment: I think the - `redirect_uri=https://localhost:3000` is not valid url. When you replace on a ngrok URL it's work because have access from internet.

Comment: ngrok did nto work as well.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it works when I only request bot scope, but fails when I request user scopes

Answer (score 3):

Redirecting to your `ngrok` address generally works perfectly.

To make it work you need to

1. have the ngrok app running your your local machine and
2. include your personal `ngrok` address in the call the Slack.

It should look something link this:

```
https://slack.com/oauth/v2/authorize?scope=commands,bot&client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://12345678.eu.ngrok.io/slack-verify/
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, adding `im:write` permission to the user token scopes was causing this issue. Slack doesn't provide any helpful error message, hence debugging becomes harder.

Changing "User Token Scopes" back to `identity.basic` and `identity.email`, made it work.

Comment: this won't work in any form for slack